# vi, getting multiple "Sorry, the command is not available in this version..." after reinstall

Tags: vim, vi, vimrc

From my .vimrc, getting:

```
line   16:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: filetype on
line   17:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: filetype plugin on
line   18:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: filetype indent on
line   21:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: syntax on
line   45:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
line   46:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
line   47:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
line   48:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
line   49:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

I can remove the lines, but I would rather know what I am really missing or need upgrading that is causing this as this file worked for me before.

Comment: I'm using debian, not ubuntu, so this may not apply.  On debian jessie, the skinny `vim-tiny` package is installed by default, which does not include the `vim-runtime` package.  I fixed my E319's by installing the more bloated `vim` package, which has `vim-runtime` as a dependency.

Comment: I got here because of the same problem. Based on the correct answer, I found out `vim` wasn't installed, but `vi` was. After installing `vim` everything worked.

Comment: In my case `:version` doesn't say anything about GUI and installing -gui-commmon or -runtime doesn't fix the problem, [it was on `~/.vimrc`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/11998).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try from within `vim` ...

```
:version
```

and if your get ...

```
Small version without GUI.
```

You are missing package `vim-gui-common`. It is probably also advisable to install `vim-runtime`. Commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gui-common
sudo apt-get install vim-runtime
```

---

Another cause might be that alternatives is pointing to the wrong one:

```
update-alternatives --display vim
```

to show what is used and ...

```
update-alternatives --config vim
```

to change to another vim. It could be that `/usr/bin/vim.gnome` is used and you need `/usr/bin/vim`

---

edit: Michael Durrant fixed it with #1 in case anyone wonders.

Comment: +1 on the answer, thanks, fixed for me too (on a puphpet.com-provisioned VM running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit): the commands mentioned in the answer above: 1) `sudo apt-get install vim-gui-common` then 2)
`sudo apt-get install vim-runtime` fixed it for me - i.e. no more `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:` errors. In fact, 1) was the fix, really when issuing command 2) I got messages saying things were already up to date: ...`vim-runtime is already the newest version.
vim-runtime set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded.`

Comment: If you don't want the GUI, you can just `sudo apt-get install vim-nox` (and then :version will report `Huge version without GUI.`)

Comment: vim-gui-common worked for me and fixed the up/down arrow issue when editing.

Answer (score 26):

You probably don't have the full version of VIM installed. To check, try executing `vim` or:

```
readlink -f `which vi`
```

For example, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS only came with `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`

Install the full VIM:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

Now you should have `/usr/bin/vim.basic`, and the `.vimrc` commands should succeed.

Comment: This worked for me on Linux Mint while the top answer did not.

Comment: Thank you for this. `vim-gui-common` wants to install a bunch of useless cruft that would eat another 143MB of disk space -- which is important when I'm trying to build a <1GB live image.

Comment: This worked for me on a headless raspberry pi. I think this is a simpler solution than the accepted answer and the original question does not reference a GUI installation.

Answer (score 8):

If this started after you've updated to 16.04, it might be b/c of the change to python 3 as the default interpreter as @luka5z pointed out.

To resolve, I updated to the latest clang-format.py file from https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/clang-format.py

and edited .vimrc lines from:

```
" Add hook for clang-format
map <C-K> ggVG :pyf /usr/local/bin/clang-format.py<cr>
imap <C-K> <c-o>:pyf /usr/local/bin/clang-format.py<cr>
```

to:

```
" Add hook for clang-format
map <C-K> ggVG :py3f /usr/local/bin/clang-format.py<cr>
imap <C-K> <c-o>:py3f /usr/local/bin/clang-format.py<cr>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you got the error by running other command like **crontab -e**, the reason is you need to select vim as your editor. Default nano will be used. So just run **select-editor**, and select vim, then the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that I had a file `~/.selected_editor` with content:

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

I rerun `select-editor` command and selected `/usr/bin/vim.basic` option - this changed the editor used by external programs.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to install vim.nox-py2:

```
aptitude install vim-nox-py2
```

and use update-alternatives to activate it:

```
update-alternatives --config vim
```

select the number corresponding to vim.nox-py2.

Comment: To be noted that this is for 16.04. Vim on Ubuntu used to have only python2 enabled, now it's python3-enabled and python2 ones in a separate package.

Comment: Python3 is default interpreter for Ubuntu 16.04. If this message appears as a result of using `py` command, replace it by Python 3 equivalent `py3`.

Comment: @luka5z your comment is the most usefull thing I found o this page!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the normal VIM version using `vim --version` as described in more detail [here](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/944#issuecomment-725305953). I happened to open the files using `vi` which was the cause in my case. Opening with `vim` instead fixed the issue.